# Looping through shapes to get Dimensions

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a a whole bunch of workbooks each containing a sheet with hundreds of shapes i need a code to select the widest shape of them and get the value of its width.
Thank you

```
    Sub GetWidestShape()
        for each shape in activesheet.shapes
        ' if shape is widest then
        ' shape.copy
        ' range("a1").value=the width of the widest shape
    end sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When posting a question, please share your code, and try to explain your problem as best as you can. Right now, it's very unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Which exact part of this problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hi again. Sorry for not being so clear in the questions. here is a piece of the code to explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a Function to return the widest shape and set its width, too

```
Function GetWidestShape(widestShpWidth As Long) As Shape
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
      If shp.Width > widestShpWidth Then
           widestShpWidth = shp.Width
           Set GetWidestShape = shp
      End If
    Next
End Function
```

that you could exploit in your Main code as follows:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim widestShp As Shape
    Dim widestShpWidth As Long

    Set widestShp = GetWidestShape(widestShpWidth) '<--| get the widest shape along with ist width 
    With widestShp
        ' ...
        ' your code to act on referenced shape
        '...
    End With
End Sub
```

---

of course the *dual* approach is also possible:

```
Function GetWidestShapeWidth(widestShp As Shape) As Long
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim widestShpWidth As Long

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
      If shp.Width > widestShpWidth Then
           widestShpWidth = shp.Width
           Set widestShp = shp
      End If
    Next
End Function


Sub Main()
    Dim widestShp As Shape
    Dim widestShpWidth As Long

    widestShpWidth = GetWidestShapeWidth(widestShp) '<--| get the width of the widest shape along with the widest shape        
    With widestShp
        ' ...
        ' your code to act on referenced shape
        '...
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @user7381321, if my answer solves your question then please accept it by   clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you

Answer (score 0):

At a guess it would be something like this....Note I haven't got access to test this right now.

```
Sub GetWidestShape()
        dim widest
        dim i as int;
        i=0

        for each shape in activesheet.shapes
          if(shape.width > widest.width or i =0) then
               widest = shape
          end if
          i++
        next
        'Do whatever you want with the shape.
        'you should be able to refrence the shape with the variable/object name "widest"
        'E.g range("a1").value=widest.width
end sub
```